# how to make my design responsive for all screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need some help to make my design responsive for small screens this little bit good for big screens but not for small please help to make it responsive.

My `welcome-message` is hiding on small screen.

```css
  body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #369ee3; 
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh; 
      position: relative; 
  }

  .welcome-message {
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px; 
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
  }

  .card {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 40px; 
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      max-width: 500px;
      width: 100%; 
      text-align: center;
      margin: 20px; 
  }

  .input-group {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

      .input-group input {
          width: calc(100% - 20px); 
          padding: 10px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 5px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          outline-color: #009edf;
          border: 1px solid #009edf;
      }

  .btn-login {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

      .btn-login:hover {
          background-color: #2980b9;
      }

  .logo-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 20px;
  }

  .h2-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 20px;
  }

  .logo {
      width: 100px; 
      height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="IMlogo.gif" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="h2-container">
        <h2 style="color: #fff; font-family: Lato,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.53333">FS Pro Console</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-message">
        <h3 style="font-size: 1.125em">
            Welcome to the FS Pro Console. Here you can manage your licenses.
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h2 style="color: #009edf; font-family: Lato,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400">
            Log in to your IM Account
        </h2>
        <form>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-login">Log in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want design on small screen like in this screenshot

[image: I want output like this]

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a **single, specific, answerable, programming issue**, please provide full details.

Comment: for restonsive disign : first step = use [meta viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag), then: [use media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could have easily do this design with **CSS flexbox and grid** instead of position absolute. However in this code if you want responsive design, you need to use media queries. I removed your .logo-container and .logo css from your styles and added this :

```
   /* ... Your other CSS (remove the .logo-container styles) ... */
   .logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 20px;
      width: 50px;
      height: auto;
  }


/* ... For responsive ... */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    margin-top:140px; /* ... Change as per your need ... */
  }

  .logo {
    top: 10px; 
  }

  .h2-container {
    top:0;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #369ee3; /* Blue background color for the page */
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 100vh; /* Using min-height for full page coverage */
            position: relative; /* Position relative to enable absolute positioning */
        }

        .welcome-message {
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 80px; /* Adjust top position */
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .card {
            background-color: #fff; /* White background color for the card */
            border-radius: 8px;
            padding: 40px; /* Increased padding for more height and width */
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            max-width: 500px; /* Set maximum width for the card */
            width: 100%; /* Make card responsive */
            text-align: center; /* Center align text */
            margin: 20px; /* Add margin for better spacing on larger screens */
        }

        .input-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

            .input-group input {
                width: calc(100% - 20px); /* Adjusting width for padding */
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin: 0 auto; /* Centering input fields */
                outline-color: #009edf;
                border: 1px solid #009edf;
            }

        .btn-login {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #3498db; /* Blue color for the login button */
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .btn-login:hover {
                background-color: #2980b9; /* Darker blue color on hover */
            }

        .logo-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
        }

        .h2-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 20px;
        }

        .logo {
            width: 100px; /* Adjust size as needed */
            height: auto;
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            .card {
                margin-top: 140px; /* ... Change as per your need ... */
            }

            .logo {
                top: 10px;
            }

            .h2-container {
                top: 10px;
                font-size: 0.8rem;
            }
        }
        @media (max-height: 600px) {
            .card {
                margin-top: 140px; /* ... Change as per your need ... */
            }

            .logo {
                top: 10px;
            }

            .h2-container {
                top: 10px;
                font-size: 0.8rem;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome-message">
        <h3 style="font-size: 1.125em">
            Welcome to the FS Pro Console. Here you can manage your licenses.
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="IMlogo.gif" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="h2-container">
        <h2 style="color: #fff; font-family: Lato,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.53333">FS Pro Console</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h2 style="color: #009edf; font-family: Lato,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400">
            Log in to your IM Account
        </h2>
        <form>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-login">Log in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```